# how to add delay function inside the ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using ajax function to update and output the result.
how can I delay like 2 secs before the second update result get display again?
since right now, after the first update and second update, the text is the same like 
'updated' I want to let user know this is the second time updated msg.

```
$.ajax({  
  type: "post",  
  url: "function.php",  
  data: "ajax=updateAward&" + inputs,
  success: function(html) { 

    $('#message_award').html(''); //clear previous text
//delay 2 sec then display below?

    $('#message_award').html(html) ;    

  }  
});
```

Comment: fyi.. You dont have to do `$('#message_award').html('');` before `$('#message_award').html(html)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout` to execute a function after a delay (given in milliseconds). Here's a complete example:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "post",  
    url: "function.php",  
    data: "ajax=updateAward&" + inputs,
    success: function(html) { 
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#message_award').html(html); 
        }, 2000);
    }  
});
```

Comment: this does delay the result, but the first result still stay there for two more sec then switch straight to the second result. I want to remove the first result right away, then have like 2 sec of display empty, then display the second result.

Comment: Simply add your code for removing the text just before the call to `setTimeout`

Comment: Or, if you want to remove the text before the ajax call is finished, then just do it right before you perform the request.